# add fields to a page based on checked checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I would like to have fields on a page based on whether the user wants them.

I have a page with checkboxes for different types of expenses. The user must check the types of expenses he has and then he'll be redirected to a new page where he can fill in the specific amounts for only the ones that he's checked.

Unfortunately I'm very new to this and all I have so far is an alert that pops up when checkboxes are checked.

How can I modify the following code to add the fields?

```
function submitCategories()
{
//TODO: get categories (checkbox)

    var searchIDs = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        alert( $(this).val());
    }).get();

//Redirect
```

Really stuck, hope this makes sense

Thanks

Comment: What exactly you need to implement?

Comment: Assuming "new page" means a new pageload, HTML is stateless so you have to do that on the serverside.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. But it does not make sense for us to do all this. What have you tried besides the JS function.

Comment: Just the function, I'm not asking you to do it for me, please, just a point in the right direction is all I need. Unfortunately my googling has come up empty handed which leads me to believe that I'm on the wrong path or my function is completely useless. Either way, some experienced minds could hopefully nudge me in the correct direction.

Comment: @Scubacode, check my answer. It may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add those id's as comma seperated string in the `query string` and redirect to the detail page and parse the values back it in server side

```
function submitCategories()
{
    var selectedQueryStr="?ids="
    var searchIDs = $(":checked").each(function () {
        selectedQueryStr+=$(this).val()+",";
    });

    window.location.href="DetailPage.aspx"+selectedQueryStr;
}
```

EDIT

based on your comment

```
function inputDetails() 
{ 
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
{ 
 if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox') 
 { if (checkbox.checked == true)  //changed
  { alert("woohoo!!!!!!!"); } 
  else { alert("please check some boxes!!") } 
  } 
} 
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a little bit lost here, yes I go to a new page but what do I put for selectedQueryStr?

Comment: Also, I stumbled upon this

Comment: function inputDetails()
       {
         var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
      {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox')
        {
            if (checkbox == ":checked")
            {
                alert("woohoo!!!!!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("please check some boxes!!")
            }

            }
        }
    }

Comment: I just put in an alert to make sure it was doing something, but I get nothing

Comment: @Scubacode, changed `checkbox.checked == true` for `woooo` :)

Comment: Thanks, but somehow I'm still not getting an alert. any advice on that?

Comment: At the risk of dragging this question out too much